# Powershell - Descomprimir archivos sobreescribiendo automáticamente

Tags: powershell

Buenos días,

Tengo un script en powersheel para que descomprima todos los archivos ZIP de la ruta actual.

Necesito hacer que, al descomprimir, se sobreescriban archivos automáticamente, sin preguntar constantemente.

Código:

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
    $files = (Get-ChildItem $file).FullName

    $shell = new-object -com shell.application

    $files | %{
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($_)

        foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
           $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item)
        }
    }
}

Expand-ZIPFile -file "*.zip" -destination (Resolve-Path .\).Path
```

¿Alguna idea?
Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente modifica la línea donde se declara el método ***copyHere***, agregando el valor **0x14**.

Aquí te adjunto el código modificado:

```
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
    $files = (Get-ChildItem $file).FullName

    $shell = new-object -com shell.application

    $files | %{
        $zip = $shell.NameSpace($_)

        foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
           $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item, 0x14)
        }
    }
}

Expand-ZIPFile -file "*.zip" -destination (Resolve-Path .\).Path
```